# Google Kick Start Time Limited on Dart

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dart

I found out that my code Time Limited, but algorithm is just fine i believe. Is it my code problem or language?
Here is the **task**:  [Task src](http://sure.%20https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff47/00000000003bf4ed)
*An arithmetic array is an array that contains at least two integers and the differences between consecutive integers are equal. For example, [9, 10], [3, 3, 3], and [9, 7, 5, 3] are arithmetic arrays, while [1, 3, 3, 7], [2, 1, 2], and [1, 2, 4] are not arithmetic arrays.
Sarasvati has an array of N non-negative integers. The i-th integer of the array is Ai. She wants to choose a contiguous arithmetic subarray from her array that has the maximum length. Please help her to determine the length of the longest contiguous arithmetic subarray.*

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

foo (array){
  var diff = [];
  var size = 2;
  var answ = 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
    diff.add(array[i + 1] - array[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < diff.length; i++){
    if (diff[i] == diff[i - 1]){
      size++;
    }
    else{
      size = 2;
    }
    answ = max(answ, size);
  } 
  return answ;
}

void main() {
  var N = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    var M = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
    String s = stdin.readLineSync();
    var intArray = [];
    s.trim().split(" ").forEach((x) => intArray.add(int.parse(x)));
    print("Case #${i + 1}: ${foo(intArray)}");
  }
}
```

Comment: problem link???

Comment: sure. https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff47/00000000003bf4ed